# How to add ProgressBar in android

Tags: android, progress-bar, progress

I'm not sure how to add a progress bar or make a loading dialog while the data is being retrieved from parse.
This is my code below for retrieving the data from parse. I've tried few tutorials but none have seemed to work for me.

```
public class HolidayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private HolidayAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_holiday);

        //noinspection ConstantConditions
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.dl);
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(Holiday.class);

        mAdapter = new HolidayAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Holiday>());

        ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.holiday_list);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        updateData();
    }

    public void updateData() {
        ParseQuery<Holiday> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Holiday.class);

        query.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.CACHE_THEN_NETWORK);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Holiday>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<Holiday> holidays, com.parse.ParseException e) {

                if (holidays != null) {
                    mAdapter.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < holidays.size(); i++) {
                        mAdapter.add(holidays.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // app icon in action bar clicked; goto parent activity.
                this.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `updateData()`:

```
public void updateData() {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, null, "Loading…");

    (…)

        @Override
        public void done(List<Holiday> holidays, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            (…)
        }
}
```

Hope it helps!